# Transfer disk image from one MacBook Air to another

Tags: migration

I'd like to migrate into a new MacBook Air I bought this week, from the previous version of MacBook Air. SSD size is the same.

Can I somehow image my older SSD and "move" it to the new SSD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both MacBook Airs have Thunderbolt, the easiest way would be to use Migration Assistant over Thunderbolt:

1. Get a Thunderbolt cable (borrow or buy).
2. Boot the old Air into Target Disk Mode (hold down <kbd>T</kbd> while booting).
3. Connect the MacBook Airs via the Thunderbolt cable.
4. On initial boot of the new Air, you'll have the option of using Migration Assistant off another Mac.
5. Select the types of items you want to copy.
6. Wait while Migration Assistant does its magic.
7. *Et voilà*, your new Air is just like your old one except newer and faster.

Comment: @ronM. Migration Assistant (in default mode) will migrate everything: apps, preferences, your user folder, random stuff you've got scattered around the root directory, remembered WiFi networks, etc. It'll get everything and (in my experience) you won't even have to re-authorize apps (from the likes of Adobe or Microsoft) that have license keys. It's really quite amazing.

Comment: @Aras There's a Migration Assistant in /Applications/Utilities.

Comment: You do not need Thunderbolt. You can use an ethernet connection, wired or wi-fi. You can even use a Time Machine backup to an external drive but it will take longer.